# CMake makes strange error, even after creating all new CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I was experimenting with CMake, until i stumped on this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34:
  Parse error.  Expected "(", got newline with text "

  ".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I though, ok fine, I'll fix the code at line 34, as suggested:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(msv-auth VERSION 0.1)

# add the executable
add_executable(app "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/app.cpp")

# app name
get_target_property(Z_APP_NAME app NAME)

# specify compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# specify C++ compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -o\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/target/debug/${Z_APP_NAME}\")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -o\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/target/release/${Z_APP_NAME}\")
endif()

#includes
target_include_directories(app INTERFACE "/usr/local/include/oatpp-1.3/oatpp")

#libs
target_link_directories(app INTERFACE "/usr/local/oatpp-1.3.0")
target_link_libraries(app oatpp)
```

But I can't seem able to fix that error even after I tried multiple times. OK, I though, let's simplify things a bit, and make a completely new CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(msv-auth VERSION 0.1)

# add the executable
add_executable(app "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/app.cpp")

# specify compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)

# specify C++ compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -o\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/target/debug/app\")

#includes
target_include_directories(app INTERFACE "/usr/local/include/oatpp-1.3/oatpp")

#libs
target_link_directories(app INTERFACE "/usr/local/oatpp-1.3.0")
target_link_libraries(app oatpp)
```

(There is only 23 lines of code in the 2nd CMakeLists.txt file)

However, running `cmake ..`, it produced this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34:
  Parse error.  Expected "(", got newline with text "

  ".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Exactly the same error on the same exact line number! Like, how can there be an error on line 34 if there's only 23 lines on the file?!

Even creating a new folder, renaming every file, or even running a completely different CMakeLists.txt on a completely different folder for a completely different project, produced the same exact error message. Even rebooting the computer did not fix it at all. I've even tried uninstall and installing CMake again, still the same issue.

Anyone ever stumped on this kind of error? How did you fix it?

Comment: Seems like you are not using the CMakeLists.txt you *think* you are or something is caching the old file somewhere. Try wiping out your build directory, re-create it, then run `cmake` again.

Comment: Where did you get the idea of hardcoding all of these compiler options? In no scenario should you be adding specifying the output file, since cmake does this itself. Also the compiler MUST be specified before the first `project` command. Ideally you move these kinds of settings to a toolchain file. As for the compiler options: you should be using `add_compile_options()` or better `target_compile_options` or set the `..._INIT` variables in the toolchain file.

Comment: Also use generator expressions and the [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY); this way the code would still work with a multi configuration generator: `set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/target/$<LOWER_CASE:$<CONFIG>>")` Adding properties with visibility `INTERFACE` to an executable target doesn't make sense btw: You won't be linking your exe to another target so all those settings don't affect any target.

Comment: CMake should be using `-O3` by default for the release configuration btw. Furthermore `if(MATCHES)` is used for regular expressions and therefore will match, if the configuration is only a substring. You probably wanted the functionality of `if(STREQUAL)`

Comment: @fabian Yes, mine is definitely a bad example. I was just cobbling up bits from many web pages, and planning to simplify things soon. Thank you for the guides, I'll definitely fix the whole thing ASAP.

Comment: @JesperJuhl After some testing I believe so. Looks like CMake stuck at some old, broken CMakeLists.txt that I made before and for some reason does not look for any CMakeLists in my project. I've fix it by trying to run some random CMake command-line args, and it suddenly fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fix it! How? For some reason, all I did was this:
`cmake . --fresh`

Well, it won't work since my CMake wasn't v3.24 (mine is v3.23) and it did complain saying that was not a known argument. However I retried `cmake .`, and suddenly it can compile the CMakeLists.txt just fine. I guess this is a bit of a bug on CMake, that for some reason it was stuck on broken CMakeLists.txt from another test project that I did before and somehow did not look at the CMakeLists.txt of my current directory? Or is it some FreeBSD bug? I don't know TBH.

Edit: for context on why my CMake was 3.23: this is the latest version on PKG for FreeBSD. I wasn't thinking of compiling CMake from source yet.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh i meant 3.24, not 3.40. Thanks for pointing that out. But the ```cmake_minimum_required``` bit was copy-pasted from somewhere, Haven't update the versioning yet, but I don't think it makes any difference, since that's the minimum required and not version-pegging.

Comment: Not sure about freebsd, but the at least on Ubuntu it's sufficient to unpack the tar.gz from the cmake website and make sure, it's in PATH (or refer to cmake via the the path to the program)...

Answer (score 1):

You don't call the good CMakeLists.

============================

Sorry to say that but your CMakeLists is ugly and aggregate many bad practices.

It should be as simple as this (you could add install target, but here is a good starter):

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(msv-auth
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION 0.1
)

find_package(oatpp REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED) # are you sure it's a direct dependency?

add_executable(app src/app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE oatpp::oatpp Threads::Threads)
target_compile_features(app PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

Everything else should be injected externally (through arguments of cmake configuration, toolchain file, CMakePresets): compiler, custom flags, exact C++ standard you want, oatpp local install path in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, etc.

Comment: "As you can see by the syntax coloration on stackoverflow" The syntax coloration of stackoverflow is wrong: CMake does allow you to escape `"` with a backslash

Comment: 1. -pthread is needed. I've tried to compile another project using oatpp manually (before trying to use CMake, just long string of clang++ arguments), and unless I specify -pthread, it will fail to compile.

2. while not necessarily fix the issue directly, I appreciate your example. I'll clean up my CMakeLists.txt ASAP. This is my first time using CMake and I was just cobbling up bits from different pages of the internet :)

Comment: @fabian, you're right, I've updated my answer. @Jacobson123, pthread was needed because you were linking oatpp manually instead of relying on `oatpp::opatpp` imported target which should carry this transitive dependency.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes ok, I'll try it soon. Since I'm doing this on FreeBSD and not on Linux, i don't know if find_package will work, since my oatpp is compiled from source and not from PKG (at least that's my rough understanding). But I'll try it later see if it works or not.

Comment: it should work if you compile from source & install it & properly set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to oatpp install prefix. It should also be fine to build & then set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to build tree of oatpp.